# "Walk my way" in the following

Tags: expressions

Can I use "walk my way" in the following situation:

> I had an argument with a bus driver about the elections, and she got really angry. So I had to get off the bus and *walk my way*.

Comment: ...unless you are deliberately quoting Frank Sinatra.

Comment: RegDwight is right! However "walk my way" attracts the reader's attention to this phrase, even if that is a deviation from the norm: 'walk' would normally be intransitive, so it would be better to say "make my way"!

Comment: Also "So I had to" is telling little. Were you told to get off or thrown off, or did you surmise that it's best to get off?

Comment: @AndrewLeach or paraphrasing Aerosmith

Comment: @Chris I surmised that it was best to get off:)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to say one of:

> So I had to get off the bus and *walk*.

Or

> So I had to get off the bus and *make my own way home/to work/etc*.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I would either "go my way" or "go my own way", but not "walk my way" unless I "walked my way *there*".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what is intended is *walk away*?